# Symfony get galleries from two entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-media-bundle

I have an entity User with relation manyToOne with Gallery.
The User entity have relation oneToMany with Insurance.
The Insurance entity have relation manyToOne with Gallery.

I want to get all Gallery relationated with User and with Insurance of the User.

In GalleryRepository I have this query:

```
qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
    $qb->select('o')
        ->join("AppBundle:Insurance", 'i')
        ->where(':user MEMBER OF o.userDocument')
        ->orWhere(':user MEMBER OF o.insuranceDocument')
        ->setParameter('user', $user);
```

But this query returns the Gallery relationated with User, and only one Gallery from Insurance (this user have two Insurance).

What i'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe the problem is you didn't join the user table in query.

Comment: @MehmetSoylu thank you for your answer. Without the join the result is the same

Comment: Instead of using orWhere use andWhere

Comment: @MarkoŽivković with andWhere, not show any result

Comment: @RL83 It seems I didn't look careful enough. In one to many relationship you store your foreign key on the many side, when I drew up your schema I see a circular reference which is never a good thing. One more thing, I notice you don't have a  `from('user`, 'o') in your query, I assume this query is in UserRepository?

Comment: @MarkoŽivković thank you for your answer. This is in GalleryRepository

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
    $qb->select('o')
        ->leftJoin("AppBundle:Insurance", 'i', 'i.user = :user')
        ->where(':user MEMBER OF o.insuranceDocument')
        ->andWhere('i.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user);
```

I get all Gallery from all User.

I'm going crazy :/